# sort lines according to number of fields in each line

Tags: sorting, awk

I have a file which has multiple fields in each line. How do I sort this file, according to the number of fields present in each line ?
For example:

```
1 3 4 6
3 4
4 5 6 7 8
5 6
6 8 7 4 6 7
```

How do I use a combination of awk and / or sort, to get this file in the following format ? i.e sorting according to the number of fields in each line, in a descending manner.

```
6 8 7 4 6 7 
4 5 6 7 8
1 3 4 6
3 4
5 6
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
awk '{print NF, $0}' file | sort -rn | cut -d' ' -f 2-
```

The awk command adds the number of fields before the line, then the sort command sorts it descending, and the cut command removes the number of fields